# What sizeof(*v) means in C?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof, size-t

I have a piece of code like this:

```
struct mystruct *v;
size_t sz;
sz = sizeof(*v);
```

What `sz` is expected to be?
What's the difference with `sizeof(struct mystruct)`?
What's the point of having `sz` in the stack (instead eg, of a `#define`)?

Comment: `sizeof` is calculated at compile time. Therefore the value of `v` at run time is irrelevant, even it it's uninitialized.

Comment: @harper, indeed what confused me is that I can't see a reason to calculate that in a stack variable.

Comment: It's not the variable itself that is used by typeof but the type of the variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof` is a compile time operator, the compiler replaces it with the relevant number. so in runtime there will be a number there - no pointer.

`sizeof(*t)` gives you the size of `T` where `t` is `T*`. 
so let's assume 
 
`char* c;`
`sizeof(c)` will give the size of the *pointer* while `sizeof(*c)` will give the size of the *character* , which is 1 byte.

Comment: Thus `sizeof(struct mystruct)` is equal to `sizeof(*v)`, right?

Answer (score 1):

> What sz is expected to be, given v is uninitialized?

`sizeof` operator doesn't have to do anything with what value operand holds.What matters to it is type.

Here `sizeof(*v)` will give size of the `struct mystruct` to which it points .

Answer (score 1):

> What sz is expected to be?

The size of the struct type in bytes, including any padding bytes.

> What's the difference with sizeof(struct mystruct)?

None, it is merely different coding styles.

> What's the point of having sz in the stack?

Supposedly the value will be used by the program further down..? You tell us.

Comment: Oh sorry I was not explicit enough: what's the advantage of having sz in the stack instead of a simple `#define`?

Comment: @GiacomoTesio Again, it depends on what it will be used for. If you need to modify it or use it for calculations, you'll obviously want to have it on the stack. If not, a define would perhaps be better.